# Rmd/Bookdown sharing sections/etc between Rmd documents

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

You have 2 documents: 1) Commercial and 2) Technical
The two should never diverge in the following sense:
Anything in the Commercial document **must**, verbatim, be in the technical document.

Is anything like the following possible in R by using Rmd/Bookdown?

In the spirit of "writing the code you wish you had":

Commercial.Rmd

````
```{r child = 'chapter_01.Rmd'}
```
````

Ch_01.Rmd:

````
## Section A
This is the sales by quarter:

```{r sales_by_quarter, results='asis'}
```
````

Technical.Rmd

````
```{r child = 'chapter_01_technical.Rmd'}
```
````

chapter_01_technical.Rmd:

````
</ Some magic to pull in 'Section A' from 'chapter_01.Rmd' \>

### Technical subsection
We define sales according to .... and handle missing data ...
```r sales_missing_data_summary
```
````

I am aware of the following:

Including a document in another

````
```{r child = 'chapter1.Rmd'}
```
````

Including R code

````
```{r shared_code}
```
````

Where the code is defined in shared.R:

```
#shared.R
#This code snippet is included in multiple places
## @knitr shared_code
a <- 10
b <- 0.05
```